# StreamWriter IO Exception - file used by another process

Tags: c#, ioexception, streamwriter

I have a big problem with my code i allways get a IO Exception and i don´t know why... I use a StreamWriter...

```
    internal void SaveOwner(Owner o)
    {
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        if (o != null)
            w.WriteLine(o.ToFileString());
        w.Close();
    }
```

Pleace can anyone help me i don´t konw i have tried everything what i konw..!?
It allways says that a other process use the file.
IO Exception - file used by another process
Befor i call the Method i asked if o != null

the code is in C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)

Comment: check if the file you are writing (path) is in use

Comment: wrap you calls inside `using` block

Comment: Is your process multi threaded and do you call `SaveOwner` from multiple threads and perhaps the same path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is caused because of multi-threading due to that I was able to reproduce your issue by that.

[Thrown Exception](http://prntscr.com/876z74)

You can simply wrap a lock (Use a static object.) and for goodness sake use the `using` keyword to wrap your stream.

```
static object syncRoot = "";

...

void SaveOwner(Owner o)
{
    lock (syncRoot)
    {
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            if (o != null)
                w.WriteLine(o.ToFileString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done it but it don´t help... I sill get the same Eception

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your calls within `using` blocks so that the object is disposed of at a proper time.

```
internal void SaveOwner(Owner o)
{
    using(StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
       if (o != null)
       {
          w.WriteLine(o.ToFileString());
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Close` calls `Dispose`. I agree it looks better, but that is not the issue here.

Comment: well `close` does call `dispose` , but a `using` block ensures it is done the proper way it should.

Comment: The issue is most likely a multi-threading issue, rather than the actual stream itself. Reproduced his problem: http://prntscr.com/876z74